# Assigning a function to a variable

Tags: python, first-class-functions

Let's say I have a function

```
def x():
    print(20)
```

Now I want to assign the function to a variable called `y`, so that if I use the `y` it calls the function `x` again. if i simply do the assignment `y = x()`, it returns `None`.

Comment: I've edited your question to cut it down to the [relevant information only.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128552/102937). Your enthusiasm is great, but in future please focus on explaining your actual question.

Comment: I also edited as what you want to do here is *assign a function to a variable*, not *assign a variable to a function*.

Comment: I think   `lambda `  should work, pls. check my answer below.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You simply don't call the function.

```
>>> def x():
>>>     print(20)
>>> y = x
>>> y()
20
```

The brackets tell Python that you are calling the function, so when you put them there, it calls the function and assigns `y` the value *returned* by `x` (which in this case is `None`).

Comment: Functions as first-class objects, *oh yeah*.

Comment: Thank you very much. Up until now, i actually somehow thought that i was pretty decent in Python :D

Comment: @geekkid: It's worth noting that **any** object can be made "callable", like a function. All you have to do is define the `__call__()` method of the object.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. I couldn't accept it right before you posted the answer, because the website wouldn't let me accept an answer so soon. Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: Can you do this with class instances?

Comment: @semjaavria Sure, methods work in the same way - try it.

Comment: @Latty thanks man, that's great to know.  this whole thread was really helpful.

Comment: @GarethLatty I have a related question: When i type y = x() into the console why does it output 20? I was merely attempting to assign the function to a variable, but this command actually executes the function, why is this?

Comment: @seeker I'm not sure what I can say that I didn't already in the answer. `()` is the signal you are calling the function. The function itself is `x` - `x()` means 'take x and call it with no arguments'. Do `y = x` and then later `y()` to call it.

Comment: @GarethLatty I just want know why it's called even when you write: y = x() . In my console 20 shows up when I write y = x(). Why is this when I haven't explicitly called the function?

Comment: @seeker `x()` is explicitly calling the function. `x` is an expression that returns the function `x`. `x()` is an expression that returns the result of calling the function `x`. `y = x()` is assigning the result of calling the function to `y`, `y = x` is assigning the function to `y`. The fact it appears in an assignment doesn't make `x()` mean a different thing.

Comment: This is what I'm saying! When I type y = x() in Windows power shell 20 is displayed after I hit enter. Usually when you assign a value to a variable nothing appears on the next line, but in this case 20 does. Why is this?

Comment: @seeker Because your function is being called. In order to get the result of `x()`, `x` must be run. In this case, it runs, printing `20` and returning `None`. Then that result (`None`) is assigned to `y`. Functions in Python (as with most languages) can have side effects. In order to call the function to get it's return value (or `None` if it has no explicit return value), the function is executed, and side effects happen.

Comment: Oh thank you, this is all I wanted to know. It was driving me mad not knowing why that was appearing! Thanks

Comment: @seeker to better undestand your issue, you should check also [Levon's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10354207/1262357) answer.

Comment: What if the function is `x(z)`, and `z` is defined later?

Comment: @alex As explained in the answer, `x(z)` is an expression that calls the function `x` with the argument `z`, not a function.

Comment: thanks, but what if i want to have like ```some_var = "x"``` and then ```y = some_var```. i want not to use if/else statements and want to call ```x``` function.

Answer (score 17):

When you assign a function to a variable you *don't* use the () but simply the name of the function.

In your case given `def x(): ...`, and variable `silly_var` you would do something like this:

```
silly_var = x
```

and then you can call the function either with

```
x()
```

or

```
silly_var()
```

Answer (score 12):

when you perform `y=x()` you are actually assigning y to the result of calling the function object `x` and the function has a return value of `None`. Function calls in python are performed using `()`. To assign `x to y` so you can call `y` just like you would `x` you assign the function object x to y like `y=x` and call the function using `y()`

Answer (score 10):

The syntax

```
def x():
    print(20)
```

is basically the same as `x = lambda: print(20)` (there are some differences under the hood, but for most pratical purposes, the results the same).

The syntax

```
def y(t):
   return t**2
```

is basically the same as `y= lambda t: t**2`. When you define a function, you're creating a variable that has the function as its value. In the first example, you're setting `x` to be the function `lambda: print(20)`. So `x` now refers to that function.  `x()` is not the function, it's the *call* of the function. In python, functions are simply a type of variable, and can generally be used like any other variable. For example:

```
def power_function(power):
      return  lambda x : x**power
power_function(3)(2)
```

This returns 8. `power_function` is a function that returns a function as output. When it's called on `3`, it returns a function that cubes the input, so when *that* function is called on the input `2`, it returns 8. You could do `cube = power_function(3)`, and now `cube(2)` would return 8.

Comment: x = lambda: print(20)  is what I'm looking for.  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

lambda should be useful for this case.
For example,

1. create function y=x+1

   `y=lambda x:x+1`
2. call the function

   `y(1)`

   then return `2`.

Comment: This did not work for the print function. I was trying to dependency inject my choice of 'logging' to a custom function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the value/usefulness of renaming a function and call it with the new name. But using a string as function name, e.g. obtained from the command line, **has** some value/usefulness:

```
import sys
fun = eval(sys.argv[1])
fun()
```

In the present case, fun = x.

Answer (score 0):

```
def x():
   print(20)
   return 10

y = x
y()
print(y)
```

gives the output

```
20
<function x at 0x7fc548cd3040>
```

so it does not actually assign the value returned by x() to the variable y.