# Python store action/method in block/array

Tags: python, objective-c

I am beginner in python and I am trying to write something like this in objective-c. In Objective-C, each method can be stored in block and those can be called again later. I have tried to find online but I don't know keyword in python. Can I write like that in python or is there any similar flow ? How shall I do?

```
void (^successBlock)() = ^{
    NSLog(@"Test");
};

NSMutableArray *muArr = [NSMutableArray array];
[muArr addObject:successBlock];

for (void (^successBlock)() in muArr) {
    successBlock();
}
```

Comment: Kind of. But as long as I can store function and do it later in python, it shall be okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are first-class members of Python. There's no extra syntax required beyond function definition. Check out this example using just standard library functions and a lambda function (which is *roughly* analogous to a block).

```
functions = [round, int, str, lambda x: x + 2]

for fn in functions:
    print(fn(3.1415))
# 3
# 3
# 3.1415
# 5.141500000000001
```

Comment: Yes. It help. I am checking out lambda function . Thanks thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Functions in Python are first class citizens and so can be stored in variables.

See [Assigning a function to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354163/assigning-a-function-to-a-variable)

```
def successBlock():
    NSLog("Test")

muArr = [successBlock]

for sb in muArr: 
    sb()
```

Comment: fixed up a couple of typos

Answer (score -1):

Try this code and it should work

```
void (^successblock)() = ^^{
    NSLog(@"Test");
};

NSMutableArray *mUArr = [NsMutableArray array];
[muArr addObject:successBlock];

for (void (^successBlock)() in muArr) {
    successBlock()
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is asking how to write the code in python.