# Assign functions to variables, and use random on them

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

Thanks for taking the time to ready thru my question.

At the moment I'm creating a method for a class, and below is what I've got so far.

```
def scramble_words_password(self, words):
    if words:
        words = words.split()
        words_count = range(len(words))

        while True:
            num = random.choice(words_count)
            del(words_count[num])
            password = [letter for letter in list(words[num])]
```

A few months ago i came across a tutorial, that explained how to assing functions to variables, and use something like random on them but i cant find it again...

What I want in my function/method is a way to randomly use `letter.lower()` and `letter.upper()` on the comprehension on the bottom line of my function/method, but how can i achieve that and still keep it all in the comprehension.

FYI, I know that the function ATM is an infinity loop, so no smart remarks please ;)

Comment: Function names act much like variables. You can pass them into other functions as parameters or make a list of functions.

Comment: I think your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354163/assigning-a-function-to-a-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning a function to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354163/assigning-a-function-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `random.choice` over a list of methods to call:

```
def scramble_words_password(self, words):
    if words:
        words = words.split()
        words_count = range(len(words))
        words_funcs = [str.upper, str.lower]
        while True:
            num = random.choice(words_count)
            del(words_count[num])
            password = [random.choice(words_funcs)(letter) for letter in list(words[num])]
```

Main call explain, `random.choice(words_funcs)(letter)`, will choose a random element from the list, as they are callables you can just pass the letter to them. Keep in mind that all methods from strings (also other built-in types) can be called statically, so a list with `str.lower` and `str.upper` will do.

Comment: Exactly what I looked for THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

Function names act much like variables. You can pass them into other functions as parameters or make a list of functions. I suggest you create a list of functions and randomly select a list element.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example? when I try to put upper() and lower() in a list I get a not defined error

Comment: Because you are calling them! You should add the function declaration (i.e. the function name) `func_list = [str.upper, str.lower]`. Then, to call a random function: `random.choice(func_list)("string")`

Comment: @Alexander use just the name. Parentheses **calls** the function.

Comment: @CarlesMitjans I suggest splitting the choice and the call into two lines.

Comment: can i ask why i got down voted?