# In pycharm what does the V mean?

Tags: python, variables, methods, pycharm

Using some classes like someclass and doing someclass. will bring up a bunch of methods, in pycharm the little icon to the left is an 'm'.

Importing random and using that gives me little 'v's. Apparently those stand for variables but they're methods/functions?

For example random.choice()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'V' means variable. Checkout [the pycharm symbol guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/symbols.html) as a reference. Remember that in python you can [store methods/functions in variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354163/assigning-a-function-to-a-variable). This is the case here.

Comment: I finally googled this after 7 years of using PyCharm and got your answer :D

Answer (score 2):

'v' does mean it's a variable, and this is because the `random.choice` is a variable that holds the real function, which you can see is really `_inst.choice` (if you hover on `choice` in `random.choice` and clicking while pressing `ctrl`)