# Class_name.apply syntax in python

Tags: python, oop, pytorch

I am new to object oriented programming and pytorch framework. I am stuck with the usage of syntax shown below:

```
self. variable_name=  some_class_name.apply
```

It would be great if someone can explain me this kind of syntax.

I tried searching this on various websites but could not find any appropriate solution.
I saw the usage of this syntax when I was trying to understand the below code:
https://github.com/liangqiyao990210/Quantum-Deep-Learning/blob/master/qiskit_demo/qiskit_demo.ipynb
Thank you for great help.

Comment: That's just an ordinary attribute lookup.  The specific name `apply` has no special meaning here.

Comment: `self` is an object.  `self.variable_name` is an attribute of that object.  `some_class_name` is, presumably, a class object, and `some_class_name.apply` is an attribute of that class.  I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: Thank you @jasonharper for your response. Can you explain a little about attribute lookup.

Comment: Thank you @JohnGordon for your response. It would be great if you can share some link where the usage of 'class_name.apply' is explained ?

Answer (score 0):

In python, assigning a function or method to a variable means that the assigned variable is a reference of the function or method. For example, we define a function `func`:

```
def func(x): 
    return x**2
```

and then we assign `func` to a variable `g`: `g=func`. After that, we can directly call the function `func` by calling `g`:

```
>>> g(3)
>>> 9
>>> func(3)
>>> 9
```

In other words, `g` is an **alias** of the function `func`.

In the link you've [mentioned](https://github.com/liangqiyao990210/Quantum-Deep-Learning/blob/master/qiskit_demo/qiskit_demo.ipynb), `self.qc = TorchCircuit.apply` simply means that we create a reference of `TorchCircuit.apply` and assign it to `self.qc`. Calling `self.qc(x)` is totally equal to calling `TorchCircuit.apply(x)`

**References**:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/assign-function-to-a-variable-in-python/

[Assigning a function to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354163/assigning-a-function-to-a-variable)

Comment: Thank you @Rancho Xia for your response. In the link I shared in the question, they write :        
      qc = TorchCircuit.apply  . Here TorchCircuit is class defined in the program. So, is this means we are creating a qc object of the class or does it mean anything different. Is apply some kind alias ?

Comment: We're definitely not creating an object. Creating an object should go something like this: `object = TorchCircuit()`. As you said, I think `self.qc = TorchCircuit.apply` creates some kind of alias. Maybe `TorchCircuit.apply` is a class method that could be called directly without creating instances and we wish to call it directly using `self.qc`. However, I didn't find the definition of `apply` either in the class `TorchCircuit` or in its parent class `Function`, so I'm not sure about how `apply` functions. The best way to figure it out is to run the code yourself and see what the `qc` is.

Comment: I checked the type of qc in the term qc = TorchCircuit.apply. It gives me the output as <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>